# How to set all RadioButton IsChecked properties to false

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, ischecked

I have 4 `RadioButtons` in a `UniformGrid`.

Initially they are all set to `false`.

But once I click one of them, one stays true at all times.

Our requirement is that they all can be set to false.

I tried things like

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

But it's not working. I know I can use a `ToggleButton`, but only one of my `RadioButtons` can be checked at a time.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works only when mouse button is actually pressed (try to hold it and you'll see).
The easiest way that comes to mind is to alter `RadioButton` a bit to suit our needs:

```
public class UncheckableRadioButton : RadioButton
{
   protected override void OnToggle()
   {
      if (IsChecked == true)
         IsChecked = false;
      else base.OnToggle();
   }
}
```

Theese custom radios will uncheck if clicked again.

Comment: @DeMama, would you mind to share your solution (via edit or separate answer)? It might be really useful for others, and quite interesting for us, who answered the question =)

Comment: Here you go. However, please note that this solution is very specific for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you right away that a style won't solve your problem because once a user sets the value of a DependencyProperty it ignores style setters, you should read up on [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#value_determination).

On the other hand you can try handling the mouse click on your own when a radio button has IsChecked=True, like so:

```
        <RadioButton GroupName="AAA" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

And:

```
    private void RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;

        if (radioButton != null && radioButton.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            radioButton.IsChecked = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

I think this does the trick.

Comment: What if keyboard is used to toggle Radios? =)

Comment: I guess that requires you user PreviewKeyDown as well, with the same code while checking if the pressed key was the spacebar...

Answer (score 0):

As [icebat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021555/icebat) requested, i'll post my solution:

I simply created an event handler for my `RadioButtons` where I compare certain values defined in my class:

```
private int PopupID;
private bool IsPopupActive;
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    string s = (string)rb.Content;
    int id = int.Parse(s);

    if (PopupID == id && IsPopupActive == true)
    {
        foreach (RadioButton rbb in PopupGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>())
            rbb.SetValue(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, false);

        IsPopupActive = false;
    }
    else if (PopupID != id || IsPopupActive == false)
    {
        foreach (RadioButton rbb in PopupGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>()
                .Where(x => x != rb))
            rbb.SetValue(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, false);

        IsPopupActive = true;
        PopupID = id;
    }
}
```

Not a big fan of code-behind solutions like this, but it works.